# How to use cygwin to access AWS linux server instance

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, cygwin

### I am trying to use Cygwin to connect to my Amazon server instance

---

***I am new to this***

- Currently i have a `USA.pem` file located at
  `C:\Users\Vinay\Desktop\Devrath`
- I have installed `Cygwin`
- I have used [this reference](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41382/how-to-use-linux-commands-in-windows-with-cygwin/) to use cmd prompt with cygwin

now i navigated to the location from command prompt

```
C:\Users\Vinay\Desktop\Devrath>
```

---

### How can i get access to my amazon server ..... what steps i need to follow

In linux terminal i used to give like this ::

```
ssh -i ~/Downloads/usa.pem ubuntu@11.213.92.234
```

Comment: you said you have it in  C:\Users\Vinay\Desktop\Devrath, but pointing for -i option ~/Downloads/usa.pem

Comment: you need to install openssh package for cygwin and then open cygwin console and issue the same command you did in linux.

Comment: @DanilaLadner  ...What command can i give in cygwin prompt so that i can install this package ...... i am a noob

Comment: you should have the client by default already installed.

Comment: @DanilaLadner  ...But when i try i get ...... ssh: command not found .......

Comment: try to use full path C:\Cygwin\bin\ssh

Comment: Why don't you go with putty anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make sure you have an SSH client installed. Open the Cygwin setup file (if you don't have it you can get it from http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Click next and leave all options default until you get to "Choose A Download Source". Make sure "Install from Internet" is selected and click next.

You can leave the options as they are on the next 3 screens, the defaults are safe and you shouldn't need to change them. Select a mirror to use and click next, any one should be fine.

From the Select Packages window type 'openssh' in the search box. Click the + to the left of  "Net". Click the text that says "Skip" once and it will change and say a version number. Click next at the bottom.

Make sure that you leave the checkbox to get the required files selected and click next. The files will be installed and then you can open the Cygwin terminal again and try the SSH command.

```
ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/Vinay/Desktop/Devrath/USA.pem user@host
```

Should work. If it doesn't, please run:

```
ssh -vv -i /cygdrive/c/Users/Vinay/Desktop/Devrath/USA.pem user@host
```

And paste the output in a comment.

Comment: Perfect ! --- This was exactly what i was looking for .... thank you :)